# Calling a async method with Task.Run inside and are those calls in order?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have this function:

```
public async void WriteError(string message)
{
    await Task.Run(() => logger.Log(message));
}
```

If I call twice:

```
WriteError("Error 1");
WriteError("Error 2");
```

Does the output in order? If not, how can I make it in order? Thanks !

Comment: Why are you offloading the logging calls to the `ThreadPool`? For performance reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the output in order?

No, it is not guaranteed.

> If not, how can I make it in order? Thanks !

Change `WriteError` to be `async Task` (note that in general case `async void` should be avoided) and await the task:

```cs
public async Task WriteError(string message)
{
    await Task.Run(() => logger.Log(message));
}
await WriteError("Error 1");
await WriteError("Error 2");
```

Or, if you really-really want fire-and-forget (though I would argue you should not do it here, there are loggers which support asynchronous log writing. Serilog for example), this is a rare case when you can try using `ContinueWith` (also requires signature change):

```cs
_ = WriteError("Error 1")
    .ContinueWith(task => WriteError("Error 2"), TaskScheduler.Default);
```